# If and cond as special forms

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

Consider these two paragraphs from [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1):

> This construct is called a case analysis, and there is a special form
>   in Lisp for notating such a case analysis. It is called cond (which
>   stands for “conditional”), and it is used as follows:
>
> ...
>
> This uses the special form if, a restricted type of conditional that
>   can be used when there are precisely two cases in the case analysis.

What does type mean in this context (restricted type of conditional)? Does it mean:

- "if" is a type of "cond"? Because the sentence states "there is a special form", so there is only one special form because "if" is one type of "cond".
- Both "if" and "cond" are unrelated. They are both conditionals. If this is correct, why does this sentence say "there is a special form" like it is only one?

Comment: There is a special form for general case analysis with support for multiple cases- it is called COND. There is a simpler special form for when there are only two cases: IF.

Comment: @Rainer Joswig Thanks. This is a little off topic. Regarding what you said about if. "only two cases:" - but why is (if (> 2 3) #t) valid? This is only one case? (if (< 2 3) #t) returns #t as expected, but (if (> 2 3) #t) returns nothing at all.

Comment: In some early Schemes the IF without the negative clause was not essential syntax. Generally in Scheme if the value is false and the second clause is not provided, then the value of the IF expression is unspecified. This means that in Scheme it typically returns something but it is unspecified what it returns. In Common Lisp it is specified to return NIL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *" `if` [is] a restricted type of conditional"*, I believe "conditional" doesn't mean specifically `cond`; it means "conditional statement / expression", in general.

So there are two, `cond` and `if`. Each can be defined in terms of the other, so a given implementation may choose to have only one of them as a primitive, defining the other in terms of it; or the implementation can choose to have both of them as primitive special forms.

Special forms are handled specially by the interpreter (compiler) itself.

Macros also can be used for that. They won't be handled by the interpreter itself then, but rather by its macros-handling mechanism.

So `if` is a conditional; `cond` is a conditional; `cond` can have any number of clauses; `if` must have exactly two (or *one or two*, depending on the standard)  clauses; all the rest is just English. :)

Comment: Thanks. This is a little off topic. Regarding what you said about if. "if must have exactly two clauses;" - but why is (if (> 2 3) #t) valid? This is only one case? (if (< 2 3) #t) returns #t as expected, but (if (> 2 3) #t) returns nothing at all.

Comment: this depends on a language/implementation. It is legal in Common Lisp, but not in Scheme, I believe. What implementation are you using? -- I've just checked in Racket, it's invalid under `#lang racket`, but indeed successfully returns "nothing" under `#lang r5rs`.

Comment: I am using r5rs. So does it mean we are allowed to use if for only 1 case in r5rs?

Comment: yes. but the return value is "unspecified", so, shouldn't be used. such `if` would only be used for its "side effects", not its return value. e.g., running `(define x (if #f 1))

(display x)` prints `#<void>`, in DrRacket under `#lang r5rs`.

Comment: Also often in language standards they just choose which one is the primitive and which one derives from the other and implementations can always choose to implement anything they like as a primitive and they often do to make their implementation faster. Both Common Lisp and Scheme defines `cond` as  a macro/derived and thus `if` is the primitive while the McCarthy paper only had `cond` and thus it was the original conditional in Lisp.  From R6RS the implementation can return whatever they seem fit should the predicate be `#f` and there are no alternative expression in the form.

Comment: @Will Ness - regarding what you said about "but the return value is "unspecified", so, shouldn't be used.", can you take a look at the make-mutex procedure here?
https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-23.html#%_sec_3.4.2
It seems the if in the the-mutex uses one case only. Is this a bug in the code? Or is this an example of the side-effect you mentioned?

Comment: yes, `(the-mutex 'acquire)` calls the procedure `the-mutex` for it to *do* something, i.e. for its side effects (not for its returned value).

Comment: @Will Ness thanks. I think I understand it now. So it turns out the book is wrong?

Comment: in what sense is it wrong? I don't think so, no. the call `(the-mutex 'acquire)` is in tail position, so it just expresses a loop. OTOH, when  `serialized-p` procedure is called (inside the `make-serializer`), it calls `(mutex 'acquire)` disregarding its return value, so all is right. --- it is not an error to call `(if T C)` in R5RS, just its return value is not specified (so shouldn't be used).

Comment: if we re-write `make-serializer` and `make-mutex` with `let` / `letrec` instead of the internal `define`s, I think it  becomes clearer. it's all about what is created first, and what second. see https://pastebin.com/d39LtEnv

Comment: @Will Ness ah, I didn't mean the code. I mean the book's statement is wrong: "This uses the special form if, a restricted type of conditional that can be used when there are precisely two cases in the case analysis". I just want to be sure so I don't misunderstand anything.

Comment: I think you got it. probably they meant the two cases - true and false - *conceptually*. (with the second possibly omitted *in code*).

Comment: @Will Ness Oh, I see. You might be right. I must have misinterpreted it.